# How to filter multiple columns in a database based on all items from multiple form listboxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with multiple listboxes. Listboxes 1 to 4 have a large items list. Listboxes 5 to 8 display the selected items from Listboxes 1 to 4 as follows: Listbox 5 shows the selected items from Listbox 1, Listbox 6 shows those selected from Listbox 2 and so on.

I want to filter a database based on items on Listboxes 5 to 8. Listbox 5 is the critera to filter the first database column, listbox 6 is the critera for second column and so on.

The below code is working but just if all Listboxes 5 to 8 have items on it. That means that if I left one or more of the Listboxes 5 to 8 empty the filter simply does not work and I got 0 records found. And thats not the idea.

In other words: I want to get the database filtered even if I don't choose data from all the Listboxes 1 to 4. I have tried multiple things but nothing worked. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Db As ListObject
Set Db = Sheets(6).ListObjects("Database")

Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
Dim x, y, z, s As Variant


'Listbox 5 to column 1

    ReDim x(0)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'For all items in the listbox
    For i = 0 To ListBox5.ListCount - 1

        x(UBound(x)) = Me.ListBox5.List(i)
        ReDim Preserve x(UBound(x) + 1)
    Next i

    'Filter first column by the selected item
    Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=x, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Listbox 6 to column 2

    ReDim y(0)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For j = 0 To ListBox6.ListCount - 1
       y(UBound(y)) = Me.ListBox6.List(j)
       ReDim Preserve y(UBound(y) + 1)

    Next j

    'Filter second column by the selected item
    Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=y, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 'Listbox 7 to column 3

    ReDim z(0)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For k = 0 To ListBox7.ListCount - 1
       z(UBound(z)) = Me.ListBox7.List(k)
       ReDim Preserve z(UBound(z) + 1)

    Next k

    'Filter second column by the selected item
    Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=z, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 'Listbox 8 to column 4

    ReDim s(0)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For l = 0 To ListBox8.ListCount - 1
       s(UBound(s)) = Me.ListBox8.List(l)
       ReDim Preserve s(UBound(s) + 1)

    Next l

    'Filter second column by the selected item
    Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=s, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    

End Sub
```

Comment: A note on declaring variables in VBA - `Dim i, j, k, l As Integer` here only `l` is an Integer, and all the others are Variant.  You need to use `As [Type]` for every variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Db As ListObject
    Dim n As Long
    Dim arr, lb As MSForms.ListBox

    Set Db = Sheets(6).ListObjects("Table1")

    Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter '<< clear filter

    For n = 5 To 8
        Set lb = Me.Controls("ListBox" & n) '<< get the list from its name
        If lb.ListCount > 0 Then            '<< ignore empty lists
            arr = ListArray(lb)
            Db.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=(n - 4), Criteria1:=arr, _
                                        Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
    Next n
End Sub

'get list content as an array
Function ListArray(lst As Object) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, arr()
    If lst.ListCount > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(0 To lst.ListCount - 1)
        For i = 0 To lst.ListCount - 1
            arr(i) = lst.list(i)
        Next i
    End If
    ListArray = arr
End Function
```